# Javascript validation not working ($Component notation problem)

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have one vf page where after clicking on Contacts tab I want check whether user has entered value in "tab1_Name" inputText under AccDetails tab.
 I am trying to access the "tab1_Name" id using $Component notation, however everytime its value is null. Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```
<apex:page controller="TestController" showHeader="true"  > 
<apex:form >
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" id="AccountTabPanel" 
    tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab"> 

    <apex:tab label="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails"> 

        <apex:inputText id="tab1_Id" label="tab1_Name" value="{!AccountList}"/>
    </apex:tab> 

    <apex:tab label="Contacts" name="Contacts" id="tabContact" onclick="validate()"> 

        <apex:inputText id="tab2_Id" label="tab2_Name2" value="{!AccountList}"/>
    </apex:tab>   
</apex:tabPanel> 
</apex:form>
<script language="javascript">
function validate()
{
try
{
var fNameObj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.AccountTabPanel.tabdetails.tab1_Id}');
alert("inside validate"+fNameObj);
if(trim(fNameObj.value) == "")
{
alert("tab1Name is mandatory!");
return false;
}
return true;
}
catch(e)
{
alert(e);
return false;
}
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

This took a little bit of troubleshooting by looking at the page source. I added an id to the `page` and the `form` tags and then looked at the source to see what the rendered id was on the tab's input field. This gave me the correct structure for the `$Component` reference path.

It turns out that the `AccountTabPanel` and `tabdetails` elements are not part of the DOM id structure. The structure that works looks like this: `document.getElementById('{!$Component.thePage.theForm.tab1_Id}');`

```
<apex:page id="thePage" showHeader="true" controller="TestController">
    <apex:form id="theForm" >
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">

            <apex:tab label="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails">

                <apex:inputText id="tab1_Id" label="tab1_Name" value="{! AccountList}" />
            </apex:tab>

            <apex:tab label="Contacts" name="Contacts" id="tabContact" onclick="validate()">

                <apex:inputText id="tab2_Id" label="tab2_Name2" value="{! AccountList}" />
            </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:form>
    <script language="javascript">
        function validate() {
            try {
                var fNameObj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.thePage.theForm.tab1_Id}');
                alert("inside validate" + fNameObj);
                if (trim(fNameObj.value) == "") {
                    alert("tab1Name is mandatory!");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue with the $Component way, you need to give an id to `<apex:form>` and start from form. As long as the VF element is wrapped in either in `<apex:form>` or `<apex:pageblock>`, you need to start with those two elements.

Otherwise, if you are using jQuery, you can simply use:

```
$('input[id$="tab2_Id"]')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I gave an id to form and started with form id but still its not working.